# onclick attribute not binding in html code while wrote inside a json data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

i have to add dynamic onclick attribute while data adding dynamically.

```
var jsondata = {
        jsonarray : [
                {data : '<button onclick="function("param")">submit</button>'}
        ]
}

$('#id').html(jsondata.jsonarray[i].data);
```

onclick attribute no binded in html code.
if is there any other alternative please provide me. anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The `"` before `param` is matching the `"` that starts the `onclick` attribute, so it's just `onclick="function("`. You need to use a different quote around the parameter than you use around the attribute.

```
var jsondata = {
  jsonarray: [{
    data: '<button onclick="function(\'param\')">submit</button>'
  }]
}

$('#id').html(jsondata.jsonarray[i].data);
```